# Retrieving same output for different instances for XGBoost regression algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I have the following [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NUtKCemSYoxw8kb3gHvbpBUs-jgnHsE4/view?usp=sharing) using the XGBoost regression algorithm to perform prediction. The problem is, however, that the regression algorithm predicts the same output for any input and I'm not really sure why.

```
data= pd.read_csv("depthwise_data.csv", delimiter=',', header=None, skiprows=1, names=['input_size','input_channels','conv_kernel','conv_strides','running_time'])

X = data[['input_size', 'input_channels','conv_kernel', 'conv_strides']]
Y = data[["running_time"]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    np.array(X), np.array(Y), test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

y_train_log = np.log(y_train)
y_test_log = np.log(y_test)

xgb_depth_conv = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:squarederror',
                  n_estimators = 1000,
                   seed = 123,
                    tree_method = 'hist',
                    max_depth=10)

xgb_depth_conv.fit(X_train, y_train_log)
y_pred_train = xgb_depth_conv.predict(X_train)
#y_pred_test = xgb_depth_conv.predict(X_test)

X_data=[[8,576,3,2]] #instance
X_test=np.log(X_data)
y_pred_test=xgb_depth_conv.predict(X_test)
print(np.exp(y_pred_test))


MSE_test, MSE_train = mse(y_test_log,y_pred_test), mse(y_train_log, y_pred_train)
R_squared = r2_score(y_pred_test,y_test_log)
print("MSE-Train = {}".format(MSE_train))
print("MSE-Test = {}".format(MSE_test))
print("R-Squared: ", np.round(R_squared, 2))
```

Output for first instance

```
X_data=[[8,576,3,2]]
print(np.exp(y_pred_test))
[0.7050679]
```

Output for second instance

```
X_data=[[4,960,3,1]]
print(np.exp(y_pred_test))
[0.7050679]
```

Comment: Delete this line: `X_test=np.log(X_data)`

Comment: @AdarshWase, thank you for your help deleting this line is giving me an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Yeah, because list has no attribute 'shape'. Why do you want to know the shape of a list? And on what line are you getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from this `X_test=np.log(X_data)`

Why are you applying `log` on the test cases while you have not applied it on the training samples?

If you take away the `np.log` completely, even from the target (y), you get really good results. I tested it myself with the data you provided us with.

Comment: Thank you @ElliTzini for your answer